# Java naming convention for boolean variable names: writerEnabled vs writerIsEnabled

Tags: java, naming-conventions, boolean

Which of the following declarations conforms to Java's naming conventions?

```
private boolean writerIsEnabled;
// with methods like
public boolean getWriterIsEnabled() 
public void setWriterIsEnabled()
```

OR

```
private boolean writerEnabled;
// with methods like
public boolean getWriterEnabled() 
public void setWriterEnabled()
```

I personally find the first name "writerIsEnabled" to be more readable, especially when you use it in an if statement like this -

```
if(writerIsEnabled)
 {
    //...
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Valid java bean names for booleans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799280/valid-java-bean-names-for-booleans)

Comment: Personally, I'd err on the side of `[is]WriterEnabled`.  This means I would call the variable `writerEnabled` and the getter `isWriterEnabled` and the setter `setWriterEnabled`.  This comes more from code auto-completion then convention though.

Answer (score 33):

As far as I know, it's this way:

```
private boolean writerEnabled;
// with methods like
public boolean isWriterEnabled();
public void setWriterEnabled(boolean enabled);
```

Either when the type is `boolean` or `Boolean`, the difference is that the Getter starts with `is` instead of `get`.

Personally I prefer the `isWriterEnabled` approach. Technologies like, for example, JSF respect that standard when accessing properties. The EL expressions are acknowledged with `is` and `get`.

Answer (score 5):

If this is in a writer class, you'd probably want to remove the Writer from your variable.

I would typically not use `Is` in my field names, but would in the methods.

Something like this:

```
private boolean writerEnabled;

public boolean isWriterEnabled();
public void setWriterEnabled(boolean enabled);
```

Although this is my personal naming convention, you should probably talk with any others who you're working with, to see what they would use.

Answer (score 3):

```
private boolean writerEnabled;
public boolean isWriterEnabled() 
public void setWriterEnabled()
```

Answer (score 2):

For the getter and setter methods, I believe the convention is `public boolean isWriterEnabled()` and `public boolean isReaderEnabled()`.
As for the variable, it should be `private boolean writerEnabled`.