# Eclipse - Generating Getters/Setters

Tags: java, eclipse

There is an option in Eclipse (Preferences -> Java->Code Style)

It allows "is" Prefix for getters if the return is boolean.

My question why does it not do the prefixing if the return is the wrapper class (Boolean) ?

Comment: Maybe because Boolean is an object? ... and this `is` setter feature is supposed to work with `boolean` only? Maybe this should be addressed to Eclipse community

Comment: I would say that it probably does not extract the type from a wrapper class. It just adds it as a return type.

Comment: I don't believe it's on-topic to ask SO to justify how Eclipse features work - odds are this will lead to wild mass guessing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Valid Java bean names for booleans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799280/valid-java-bean-names-for-booleans)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is simply because per the **java beans specification/convention/implementation** is prefix is only intended for primitive objects.

You can take a look at the PropertyDescriptor class source (getRealMethod):

```
 if (readMethodName == null) {
    Class type = getPropertyType0();
    if (type == boolean.class || type == null) {
        readMethodName = "is" + getBaseName();
    } else {
        readMethodName = "get" + getBaseName();
    }
    }
```

So eclipse is only conforming to this.

Edit: now why the property descriptor is made this way is another question, probably Java folks decided that the possibility of null return type and the "is" prefix may be misleading.

Comment: This is not the reason. answer should tell why

Comment: @Ruchira The question is why is eclipse not allowing it => the answer because it tries to be conform to the PropertyDescriptor behaviour since many projects are using it (eclipselink, hibernate validator, etc). And allowing to use "is" prefix with Boolean properties can lead to unexpected behaviour.

Comment: first of all this is not a behavior of `eclipse`. This is behavior of `Java`

Answer (score 2):

**boolean** is a primitive type and **Boolean** is an object. An object has other properties aside from just being *true* or *false*. So perhaps this is the reason why they designed it for the primitive type only.

If there's a getter named *isActive*, you would want it to return either *true* or *false*, not **null** or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

In primitive type `boolean`, only `true` and `false` are possible. But if you use Object type `Boolean`, `null` is also accepted. Normally is not suitable in such a scenario.

```
  public class MyClass{
   private boolean status;
   private Boolean sts;

   public boolean isStatus(){
      return status;
   }

   public Boolean getSts(){
      return sts;        
   }

   // setters
  }
```

When we call `isStatus` result definitely true or false. It is make sense. But `isSts` can return `null`. This is some what not logical. This may be the reason to use get for `Object` type.

Comment: I dont see how the possibility of null is relevant for the getter prefix

Comment: It is. `object.isSomething()` should return a boolean, period. It's IMO a bad design and very unusual to return an other value.

Answer (score 0):

When the *isFoo/setFoo* special case of the getter and setter naming convention for properties was established, **Boolean** was considered more closely related to all other object types than to the **boolean** primitive type; the result of *getFoo* can be null, the result of *isFoo* cannot.

Now that the Java language has automatic boxing and unboxing of primitive types, there's a greater chance of **Boolean** variables interacting with **boolean** properties, but **Boolean** properties remain unusual because setting them to null remains a strange and usually troublesome use case.