# Hibernate - Unable to resolve property error when accessing new data field

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm modifying an exising POJO to include a boolean field, and want to display said Categories based on the boolean value.

To do so, I have updated the Hibernate XML configuration and added the fields to the database.  My issue is that a HibernateQueryError is thrown on the `Criteria.list()` method when returning the data because Hibernate cannot resolve the new field.

Category POJO:

```
public class Category implements java.io.Serializable {

private long id;
private String name;
private Short displayOrder;
private Boolean enabled;
private Set<Submission> submissions = new HashSet<Submission>(0);

   //getters and setters
   public Boolean getEnabled(){
      return this.enabled;
   }

   public void setEnabled(Boolean enabled){
      this.enabled = enabled;
   }
```

Added mapping to hibernate config:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.jason.app.hibernate.Category" table="CATEGORY" lazy="false">
    ... other properties

    <property name="enabled" type = "java.lang.Boolean">
        <column name="IS_ENABLED" />
    </property>

    ... set mapping configuration

</hibernate-mapping>
```

and this is the trouble spot:

```
private boolean hasDisplayOrder;
private boolean isEnabled;

public List<V> list() {

    try {
        Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(returnedClass());

        if (hasDisplayOrder && isEnabled){
            criteria = criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("enabled", true))
                                .addOrder(Order.asc("displayOrder"));
            log.info("Category object is enabled, added to criteria");
        }
        else if (hasDisplayOrder ) {
            criteria = criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("displayOrder"));
            log.info("Object does not contain enabled method");
        }

        return criteria.list();
    }
    catch (RuntimeException re) {
        log.error("Could not retrieve list results for class "
                + returnedClass.getSimpleName(), re);
    }

    return null;
}
```

The logging statement inside the first conditional triggers in the logs, and then an error message is printed out.

```
2014-02-12 12:02:49,482 INFO  [com.jason.app.manager.BaseManager]  Category object is enabled, added to criteria

2014-02-12 12:02:49,489 ERROR [com.jason.app.manager.BaseManager] Could not retrieve list results for class Category
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: enabled of: com.jason.app.hibernate.Category
```

Things I've tried:

- Change data type from boolean to Boolean in `Category`
- change type from `boolean` to `java.lang.Boolean` in hibernate config

The web form that this POJO is used for displays just fine if I remove the conditional inside the `list()` method above, but it shows all categories regardless of state.

Are there any other options to try out?

Comment: Please tell me the package of this Category class.I know in logs it is showing com.jason.app.hibernate .But i need to be sure

Comment: It is.  That's where the domain objects reside along with their corresponding CLASSNAME.hbm.xml mappings

Comment: Did you recently add this column in your database.Please check if the column name is spelled correctly

Comment: Column name is correct in the xml.  The field was recently added into the oracle db as a `Number(1)` and contains either a 1 or zero.

Comment: Change your `getEnabled()` to `isEnabled()` and I would use a `boolean` instead of a `Boolean` (unless the field can actually be `null`). Boolean fields don't have a `get*` method the have an `is*` method. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799280/valid-java-bean-names-for-booleans

Answer (score 0):

What if you switched your Java code to use `Boolean` instead `boolean`, something like this:

```
private boolean enabled = true;

public boolean isEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}

public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}
```

Comment: Already tried it, along with `getEnabled()`, both with primitive and object.  Nothing worked.