# Java method naming for boolean methods and call/invoke usage

Tags: java, methods, naming-conventions

Methods that return boolean are usually named with 'is' prefix - isTrue(), isSet(), isNull(), etc. 
Is it against convention to have plurals in such names like - areTrue(), areNotNull(), etc?

Also in what cases can a method have a 'call' or 'invoke' prefix. Can I use 'call' prefix to call a DAL method from business layer, like callCreateUser()?

Comment: Java Bean convention has relied on "isTrue" or "hasTrue" since Java 1.0.  You'll be contradicting that standard.

Comment: How would you have a plural boolean?

Comment: `has` is not a valid prefix.  Options are `is` or `get`. Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799280/valid-javabeans-names-for-boolean-getter-methods

Comment: Thank you for correcting me.  I didn't know.

Comment: Regarding your second paragraph, why name something “callCreateUser” when you can name it `createUser`?  The fact that it delegates to another object is an implementation detail that should not be exposed in the name.

Comment: @VGR, makes sense. When is it be appropriate to use call/invoke in the method name? Or is it never recommended. I have seen some apis with such names. Just can't find them at the moment.

Comment: I would say almost never.  After all, every method is a call/invocation.